# What clock does the SPI SCLK use?

Tags: pi-3b+, pi-4, spi

I would like to set the PWM and GPCLK pins to use the same clock source as the SPI bus uses, As mentioned by an answer to a [previous question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113289/what-are-the-capabalities-of-genral-purpose-clocks) The PWM and GPCLK can be set to the following sources:

```
0      0 Hz     Ground
1      19.2 MHz oscillator
2      0 Hz     testdebug0
3      0 Hz     testdebug1
4      0 Hz     PLLA
5      1000 MHz PLLC (changes with overclock settings)
6      500 MHz  PLLD
7      216 MHz  HDMI auxiliary
8-15   0 Hz     Ground
```

Which one is it?